# How to add References in Bibliography without a specific Author

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apa-style

I want to refer to a report available on a particular site. Although some human being must have compiled the report, but there isn't any reference to any specific name. Which BibTeX attribute should I choose for such citing.

Comment: From the website, can't you contact someone? It is quite useless to reference a document with no author, just a url link. The latter will probably die soon. I'd first try to have the document uploaded on an open archive repository and then reference the link (arxiv or oai reference is better and available with biblatex) which should then be accessible in the long term. url in general should be avoided.

Comment: In German you can just write "without Author" (German: Ohne Verfasser) as Author or you use the field `editor` with the name of the institution.

Comment: Is there anything like an organization or so that is acting like an editor or publisher and that you could use?

Comment: @BenediktBauer: Yes, there is name of organization. And also, that particular report also has a title. All is ok, except no Author, but a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility, and depending on the bib style use, would be to use

```
@misc{citekey,
  title = {Title of the report},
  year = 2012,
  note = {\url{web address of the page}}
}
```

Load the package `url` (or similar) for proper treatment of `\url`

Comment: I was thinking in the line of misc, perhaps this maybe the best way to go about it.